# Shorten the regex usage syntax in Python

Tags: python, regex

I apologize because I am coming from Perl and I am new to Python.

The following example looks very long to me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
r = re.compile('(?i)m(|[ldf])(\d+)')
m = r.match(text)
if m:
    print m.group(2)
```

In Perl for example it is only one line and it's pretty readable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print $2 if /m(|[ldf])(\d+)/i
```

How can I rewrite my Python example to be simpler. If possible to be as light as it is with Perl.

I am planning to write plenty tests and if I want to keep my code readable I would like to avoid consuming lines that will not help people to understand my program. I guess that something like this below would be more readable that my first solution:

```
r = R()
if r.exec('(?i)m(|[ldf])(\d+)', text):    print r.group(2)
if r.exec('(?i)k(|[rhe])(\d{2})', text):  print r.group(2)
```

Unfortunately in this case I have to write a class for this.

Comment: compiling the pattern is not mandatory.

Comment: Something in one line in perl can/should not necessarily be one line in python.

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Adding to khelwood's comment: Python is not Perl. Don't try to cram Perl syntax into Python (like a regular expression or something else).

Comment: If anything you should be making your regexeps longer to increase clarity and readability, see [Verbose Regexps](http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/verbose.html).

Comment: `os.system('perl your_perl_script.pl')` to get full compatibility with Perl’s syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python way values clarity over brevity, so things are generally going to be more verbose than they are in Perl. That said, the `re.compile` step is optional.

```
m = re.match('(?i)m(|[ldf])(\d+)', text)
if m:
  print m.group(2)
```

In Python, assignments are not expressions; they can't be used as values. So there's no way to skip the separate assignment statement (`m = ...`) or combine it with the `if` .  And if you want to refer to the match object later, you do need an explicit assignment - there's no global implicit state analogous to the Perl `$n` variables that stores the capture groups automatically.

Comment: @nowox what's the definition of "affectation" in this context? It's not coming up in the dictionary so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: See edit; stated explicitly now.

Comment: I think  nowox meant "assignment", @NewWorld.